# Pivot and get count of rows in each cell?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

The following query gives me the `year` and `month_num` of each support ticket.

```
SELECT STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(created_at, '%Y') AS year, 
  STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(created_at, '%m') AS month_num
FROM zendesk.zendesk
```

I want to pivot the year values and show the `COUNT(*)` of all source rows in each cell, like this:

```
    2014    2015    2016
01     5     ...     ...
02     8
03    12
04    22
05    30
06    15
07    10
08     9
09   ...
10
11
12
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(created_at, '%m') AS month_num,
       SUM(CASE WHEN STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(created_at, '%Y') = '2014' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_2014,
       SUM(CASE WHEN STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(created_at, '%Y') = '2015' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_2015,
       SUM(CASE WHEN STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(created_at, '%Y') = '2016' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_2016
FROM zendesk.zendesk
GROUP BY month_num;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  month_num,
  MIN(CASE WHEN [year] = '2014' THEN cnt END) AS year_2014,
  MIN(CASE WHEN [year] = '2015' THEN cnt END) AS year_2015,
  MIN(CASE WHEN [year] = '2016' THEN cnt END) AS year_2016
FROM (
  SELECT 
    STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(created_at, '%Y') AS [year], 
    STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(created_at, '%m') AS month_num,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM zendesk.zendesk
  GROUP BY 1,2
)
GROUP BY 1
```